# Put method cant receive body data but work with direct URL pass parameter

Tags: rest, api, postman

i call api using postman ... api work fine with if i choose put method and pass a url like:

> https://URL/user/123?id=123&name=foo

but if i using this link :

> https://URL/user/123

And pass data in body put method not working.
I try to use form-data and x-www-form-urlencoder .. all not working .
Anyone know what is my problem ..
thank for your help.
and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RAW format with particular data-type/content-Type which your using in web service Eg: JSON(application/json) Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Check the format of your request and parameters your passing

Comment: I resolve my problem .. it's server's problem . not client.. This Put method write like Get ... i need send params not bodyData :D

Comment: Okay that's fine